# Entity Framework Deleting Virtual Property Results With Empty Migration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have searched for empty migrations, and those solutions (ie. clean solution/build) have not worked for me.  I am wondering if there might be something more going on.

I have an entity...

```
public class Term
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
}
```

When this entity is built in the database, it creates a column "Organization_Id".  The Organization entity is straight forward.  Nothing weird.  Per usual when running add-migration, it also creates a foreign key constraint and index on the "Organization_Id" pointing towards the Organization entity.

We are dropping the link to the Organization entity.  So, naturally we delete the virtual property and then run add-migration.  I expect to see the dropping of the "Organization_Id" column, but it is an empty migration class.

```
public partial class termremoveorg : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

After trying a hundred different things, I am at a loss.  I even manually added dropping the column by manually setting up...

```
public partial class termremoveorg : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.Terms", new[] { "Organization_Id" });
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Terms", "Organization_Id", "dbo.Organizations");
        DropColumn("dbo.Terms", "Organization_Id");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Terms", "Organization_Id", c => c.Int());
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Terms", "Organization_Id", "dbo.Organizations", "Id");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Terms", "Organization_Id");
    }
}
```

But when I run the update-database, the database table successfully has the "Organization_Id" column deleted.  But I get the following error when the Seed() method gets to the point in the code where a few Term objects are inserted into the database (they do not reference any link to Organization records)...

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Organization_Id'.
```

Thanks for any insight or help.

**Update #1**
Per requested, here is the Organization class.

```
public class Organization
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Term> Terms { get; set; }
}
```

Looking closer at this code I realized there was a property pointing back to Terms that was not removed before running the add-migration.

Trying it out, I removed this property as well and the add-migration ran as expected and successfully.

Comment: can you show the code of `Organization` model ?

Comment: @Sampath I just added the organization code.  Looking at it I realized there was a property pointing back to the term class.  Duh!  Sometimes you can look at things and keep missing it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to `1 : M` relationship with the `Organization : Terms` where you have to remove both end points.In other words you have to remove `public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }` on the `Term` and `public virtual ICollection<Term> Terms { get; set; }` on the `Organization`.Then you will not have any issue with the Migration script.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks!